# ASP MVC: Open a view from a view with a really big string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that contains a very long string (>1000 characters). In that view, I want to open another (full) view in its own page and I want the model for that view to be the really long string. So it looks like this:

First view:

```
@model myDataStringWithManyLongStringsInIt<string>

@{
    foreach (string s in Model)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Show long string", "LongStringView", new { longString = s }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

And in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult LongStringView(string longString)
{
    return View(longString);
}
```

And in my view LongStringView:

```
@Model string
<div class="row-flud">
    <div class="span12">@Model</div>
</div>
```

My problem is when I run this code my longString is too long. So I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
```

I also tried this in my first view, but the result is the same:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test!", "LongStringView", "MyController", new { longString = s }, new { target="_blank"})
```

If I do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test two!", "LongStringView", "MyViews", longString, null)
```

Then my function LongStringView in my Controller gets called, but its input variable longString is always null. :(

So what I want to do is to from one page (view) I want to open up another page (view) and in that other page I want to show the really long string that I have in my first page.

What am I doing wrong and how should I do this?

Comment: This is the wrong direction. Turn back now. As a thumb rule you should minimize network traffic on websites.

Comment: How do you recieve these strings? Can you share the API that you get the strings from? More importantly what exactly do you get from the API? Just a list of strings?

Comment: I get the strings from another application (via its API). It's a custom object that, for the sake of argument, contains several lists of very long strings.

Comment: So nothing else, just the strings? No identifier of any kind? Will one list of strings change between two requests?

Comment: It's a bunch of search results without identifiers. Each search result is a really long string and I present a short version of it but the user should be able to see the whole thing. So yes, one list of strings will change between two requests (unless of course it's a search for the exact same thing...).

Comment: The author of the other application deserves something horrible then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right according to your comments you only got the string without proper identifiers.

One way to solve this would be processing the strings server side, and store them with newly created identifiers but this way your application wouldn't be stateless, so let's do it in an even easier (but not really optimal) way:

Forget the controller, there is no need for additional actions. Just check the view:

```
@foreach (var result in results)
{
    var shortString = result.Substring(0, 99);
    <section>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">@shortString</div>
            <a href="#" class="full-link" data-long-string="@result">See long version</a> 
        </div>
    </section>
}

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you need a little javascript (attaching the opening of the modal to the click event, and switching the contents of the modal):

```
$(function() {
    $('.full-link').on('click', function () {
        var longString = $(this).data('longString');
        var $myModal = $('#myModal');
        var $bodyElem = $myModal.children('.modal-body');
        $bodyElem.html(longString);
        $myModal.modal('show');
    });
});
```

As for where to put this javascript. Your best bet would be to make a javascript file put this script in there and reference it somewhere after you reference jquery. Like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ... ALL YOUR LAYOUT GOES HERE ...

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="path/to/yourscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is it at the bottom of the body tag.

Comment: Sorry for being a complete newbie on these GUI stuff (it's not really my bag of tricks, as you may have noticed), but where (in what file) should I put the javascript function?

Comment: I put it in _Layout (inside a script language="javascript" block), and I changed "('longString')", to "('longString');" and "('#myModal')" to "('#myModal');" which I assume were typos on your part. But the modal window doesn't show for me when I click the link.

Comment: You nearly got it right. I do made a mistake as I was using a combined var statement (var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;) but I have edited my code so it's a little cleaner how I intended it. As for where to put this script: It should be after the <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> tags in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to pass a >1000 char parameter in your URL? Sounds like a bad plan.

How about reloading the long string from the database in `LongStringView`? You can then just pass the ID or whatever parameter to the method to identify what string to load.

Alternatively you could use a JQueryUI dialog or similar to display the string without having to post back to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The thing is, I have a view A which Model is an object that contains a lot of strings. Imagine the Model of view A is a List<string> and each string is >1000 characters. The view A shows a truncated version of each string, but I want the user to be able to see the entire string in another page. So how should I go about doing that? I'm not getting the string from a database but from an API. What should my approach be?